# jquery ajax returns element not found

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have a REStful webservice (java, jersey) to do some stuff.
every function that calls an ajax request (GET or POST) with an url to the REST controller works fine... except of the recent ones and I do not know why.. i tried everything and stuck with this problem for nearly three days (wrote 3 different functions, changed from GET to POST, rewrote the function with new pathannotiation, tried to call on pageload.. renamed everything), I realy appreciate ANYTHING that could help me...

if the url contains rest/* the controller forwards it to the class which implements the needed functions..

JS function

```
function testFunc() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "rest/name/wut",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response) {
            alert("LSKDFJLSDKJFLKSD " + response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert("ma oidaaaa " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }

    });
};
```

Java Code in the RESTClass...

```
    @GET
    @Path("/wut")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    private String wut() {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("print", "wuut");
        return json.toString();
    }
```

It does not matter if the method is doing anything useful or not... it just returns 404 no element found.
(it is not even called) Therefore i tried different new methods in the RESTClass... like:

```
@GET
@Path("/wut")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
private String wut() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(url);
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    return response.toString();
}
```

I am using this snipped in another method, which is working.. I replaced the real URL with "url" for posting btw.

I also tried different MediaTypes: WILDCARD, TEXT/PLAIN...
And to just return a String...

Anyone any ideas (and SORRY for the bad english, I am really desperate so i did not do a spellcheck and english is not my native :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

- First, declare your wut() method as public: `public String wut()`
- Second, try to call your method in a browser, for example `http://localhost/rest/name/wut` and see what happens

Comment: tried the last one: Blank Page + Firefox console says: 
"The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature."

Comment: Does declaring your method as `public` make a difference?

Comment: i am an idiot... public it is...
now i am feeling really dumb xD
Thank you very much...

Comment: You're welcome :-) Don't worry, I know exactly how that feels!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use an absolute path:
Change:

```
url: "rest/name/wut",
```

to

```
url: "/rest/name/wut",
```

The error message tells me that, your client did not try the address the server provides.

Comment: tried that, exception followed: The requested resource is not available.